# Fotorama.io: how to make HTML inside clickable?

Tags: fotorama

I want to use Fotorama.io to show HTML content. But it appears that HTML is not clickable inside slider. Is there any possibility to make it work inside Fotorama?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.fotorama__select` class on your frames to make it clickable and selectable:

```
<div class="fotorama">
  <div class="fotorama__select">One</div>
  <div class="fotorama__select"><strong>Two</strong></div>
  <div class="fotorama__select"><em>Three</em></div>
</div>
```

http://fotorama.io/customize/html/#selectable-text